# How to clone the code from master branch in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Bitbucket in my project. When I am cloning the code on my local machine with my branch URL I am getting the updated code of my branch and unable to see the changes in the other branches. How to clone the updated code from all branches in Bitbucket?

Comment: Which command did you use?

Comment: @ Nabin Khadka this is the command i used for my branch https:/username@bitbucket.org/project/project.git

Comment: git clone your_git_url.git

Comment: @swathi, do you maybe mean `git pull` or `git fetch` to _update_ a branch? By default `git clone` retrieves all branches and creates remote tracking branches for them, e.g. `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

First check which branch you're on and if you have already checked out the master branch:

`git branch`

You should see something like, although the names will probably be different:

```
  dev
  master
* test
```

Switch to the master branch. If master WAS NOT listed in the previous step run the following:

`git checkout -b master origin/master`

If master WAS listed just run:

`git checkout master`

You will now be on the master branch. Now do a `git pull` for the latest updates.